# Copy >10 columns multicolumn listbox in Userform to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox, userform

I tried several solutions from several forums but nothing seemed to help.

I am pretty sure that I am making some stupid mistake and the solution is right before my eyes, but I cannot make it work.

I need to fill a *listbox* in a user form with 12 columns.

As far as I know, for more than 10 columns, one can no longer use the ***.List(i)*** attribute but must use an array to populate it. My problem is that everytime I need to insert a new line into the *listbox*, I need to copy the items in the *listbox* to the *array*, *redim* the *array* to have one more line, "insert" the new data into this new line and, finally, copy the *array* into the *listbox*.

My code is as follows:

```
iLine = lbPlanPreview.ListCount
ReDim arr(iLine, lbPlanPreview.ColumnCount - 1)

If iLine > 0 Then
    ReDim arr(0 To iLine - 1, lbPlanPreview.ColumnCount - 1)

    'Array Lines
    For iCur = 0 To iLine - 1
        'Array Columns
        For iCurAux = 0 To lbPlanPreview.ColumnCount - 1
            arr(iCur, iCurAux) = Me.lbPlanPreview.ListIndex(iCur, iCurAux)
        Next iCurAux
    Next iCur
End If
```

It always gives a type mismatch error:

[image: Error message]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, the line: arr(iCur, iCurAux) = Me.lbPlanPreview.ListIndex(iCur, iCurAux)

Comment: As mentioned correcly in OP the `.AddItem` method fails for more than 10 columns. BTW C.f. correct use of `List` function in answer below :-;

Comment: `ListBox.ListIndex` returns the selected item.

Comment: Thank you to all. It solved it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct `ListBox.List` function**

Think your last array assignment to restore prior data should be stated as follows and possibly be limited to `lbPlanPreview.ListCount - 1`:

```
'Array Lines
 For iCur = 0 To lbPlanPreview.ListCount - 1    ' possibly instead of: ILine - 1
    'Array Columns
    For iCurAux = 0 To lbPlanPreview.ColumnCount - 1
        arr(iCur, iCurAux) = Me.lbPlanPreview.List(iCur, iCurAux)
    Next iCurAux
 Next iCur
```